# What's the distance between the center of mass and geometrical center of Earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, earth, geophysics

With a good approach we can say that they are identical. But how accurate is this approach? Since Earth is not homogeneous there must be (can be) some difference. In other words I'm asking if Earth was homogeneous (but still the same shape including mountains, etc.) how far its CM would be from the actual CM?

**Edit**

My question was about the distance between the  geocenter and the center of figure (geometrical center). Based on David Hammen's answer it's about 9m.

Comment: How do you define the geometrical centre of the Earth as its surface is irregular and changing all the time due to continental drift?

Comment: Since there are maps of the surface and we know the height of each point, it is possible to calculate the geometrical centre. Since the continental drift is so slow I think we can neglect it. Or if not then the calculation could apply to a given moment, ex. now, or 1970-01-01 or what you want. I'm just rather interested if some has made similar calculations before

Comment: Sure, they must be very close to each other, I'm just wondering _how_ close. Is it some millimeters, some meters or even one or more kilometers?

Comment: Read this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_centre_of_Earth

Comment: [RAS PN 07/33: NASA scientist finds a new way to the centre of the Earth](https://www.ras.org.uk/search/article-archive/1252-ras-pn-0733-nasa-scientist-finds-a-new-way-to-the-centre-of-the-earth). N.b some measures include mass of oceans and atmosphere, some don't

Comment: Unfortunately this is only about the motion of the CM

Comment: See also [EarthScience.SE].

Comment: Why the votes to close? It's very clear what is being asked here.

Comment: [Paper discussing exactly this, but for Venus](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103584711535).

Comment: [Another paper discussing exactly this, but for Mars](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/JB080i020p02909/full), and yet [another paper discussing exactly this, but for the Moon](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1974lpsc....5.3049K).

Comment: *Unclear what you're asking* might be not exactly the correct close reason, but it is unclear to me what the physics question here is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Geophysicists use three different centers to describe the "center" of the Earth:

- The geometrical center of figure of the surface of the solid Earth (excluding oceans and seas, ice, and air),
- The center of mass of the solid Earth, and
- The center of mass of the Earth as a whole, also known as the geocenter.

They differ from one another by up to 60 meters, being greatest at times when the Earth is undergoing a significant glaciation. This is rather small compared to the two kilometer offset between the Moon's center of figure and center of mass.

[Wu, Ray, and van Dam, "Geocenter motion and its geodetic and geophysical implications," *Journal of Geodynamics* 58 (2012): 44-61.](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/CORS/Articles/Geocenter-J-Geodyn2012.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for finding this paper and making a summary. Basically all information answering my original question can be found on Fig. 2

Comment: As I calculated based on Fig.  2, currently the distance between the geocenter and the center of figure (geometrical center) is only 20 meters. Quite surprising I think

Comment: Sorry, it's 9 meters, I compered wrong lines

Comment: could you help a bit, please? As I wrote above based on Fig. 2. int this paper, I calculated 9 meters. But it's not clear to me, what it actually means. It seems like some kind of motion, but on he vertical axis, it says "meters" and not "meters/year" or "meters / 1000 years" or something similar. On Fig. 5, it's clear that Δt = 1 month. But I don't understand what's Δt for Fig. 2. If there is at all... Anyways, I'm confused, this 9 meters seems too small to me and I also found in this paper https://goo.gl/pPWD8l on page 174 that it's 0.8 km. Something's misunderstood here...